# How is density of a substance in grams per cubic centimeter a discrete attribute?

Tags: data-mining

I'm going over the different types of attributes in data-mining (nominal, ordinal, discrete, etc) and there is one example in the book that states that the density of a substance in grams per cubic centimeter is a discrete attribute. Why is this? I confuses me that this is the case but it also says that the distance from the center of campus is continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book is wrong.  Density is continuous.  It could be any real number.  You are quite right.